# Static variable and the Enterprise Library will this cause connection leaks?

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, static-members

Will the following code cause additional connections or references created by dbConn to not be disposed of properly?

It seems to me it would because it is stored in a static member.

```
public static Database dbConn = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("LocalSqlServer");
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this connection is stored in a static variable does not affect the state of other connection objects that you create from it.

As long as you close the connection when you're done with it you should be fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate please, because I am having a hard time seeing that because the first object that is instantiated is set to a static member, and it seems to me that any references it creates will not be disposed of properly until the app domain recycles and thus not be released back to the connection pool.